# Struts2 login error with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, struts2

I have created a simple login application for Struts2 but I can't login with a local MySQL database. My code is the following:

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="loginprocess">  
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"></s:textfield>  
    <s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>  
    <s:submit cssStyle="float:left;" value="Login"></s:submit>  
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**loginerror.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Login</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        Sorry username or password error!  
    <jsp:include page="login.jsp"></jsp:include>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

**main.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD  
Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  
<struts>  
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">  
<action name="loginprocess" class="com.login.struts2.LoginTest">  
<result name="success">main.jsp</result>  
<result name="error">loginerror.jsp</result>  
</action>
</package>  
</struts>
```

**LoginDao.java**

```
package com.login.struts2;
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  

public class LoginDao {
public static boolean validate(String username, String password){  
 boolean status=false;
 Connection conn = null;
  try
  {  
   String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/struts_register2";
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "1235");
   PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from test where username=? AND password=?");  
   ps.setString(1,username);  
   ps.setString(2,password);
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
   status = rs.next();
 }
 catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
 return status;  
}
}
```

**LoginTest.java**

```
package com.login.struts2;

public class LoginTest {  
    private String username,password;  
    public String getUsername() {  
        return username;  
    }  
    public void setUsername(String username) {  
        this.username = username;  
    }  

    public String getUserpass() {  
        return password;  
    }   
    public void setUserpass(String password) {  
        this.password = password;  
    }  

    public String execute(){  
        if(LoginDao.validate(username, password)){  
            return "success";  
        }  
        else{  
            return "error";  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If I try to change the query at `LoginDao.java`, by having `OR` instead of `AND`, it redirects me to `main.jsp`. I can't find a solution.My database has the fields with `"test" (VARCHAR(10)` for username and password. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your input and what does the select return? did you log username and password before inserting them to the stmt?

Comment: the password length should be large enough to store strong passwords.

Comment: @thst My input is test for both username and password fields the only record at the Database at the moment. http://s27.postimg.org/obgoxvd4j/testdb.png

Comment: Please log the values of username and password to stdout, this may show unexpected characters. Your code looks ok.

Comment: If the SQL query isn't returning what you think then either the username/password combo isn't what you think, or the values in the DB aren't what you think. In either case you have to take a step back and check your assumptions.

Comment: I logged the values of username and password to stdout. The console gives the following: Username = test Password= null
 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.The password is test for sure at the database as it is shown at the image I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input field for the password has a name `password`.

```
<s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>
```

Then the setter should be the same name.

```
public void setPassword(String password) {  
    this.password = password;  
}
```

In this way the parameter will be populated and you will not have `null` value.